# Install python packages on shared host

Tags: python, shared-hosting

I would like to know if it is possible to install (without using shell - I don't have any permissions to use command line) python packages on a shared host. (Do not ask to change host provider)

Also, on that host is installed Python and Django and I would like to install : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt on server.

Is that possible?

Comment: you should just ask the host - if it is a common package they may do it for you

Comment: I know that. I just wondered if I can do without involving them.

Comment: xlwt doesn't need to be installed system-wide. Just place the xlwt folder into your Django project as you'd do with an app and use it from there.

Comment: You're wrong. http://www.simplistix.co.uk/presentations/python-excel.pdf#Installation. You still need to execute cmd lines

Comment: It should (and does here). How do you try import xlwt? Maybe you placed it outside of the python path? (In a django environment you'd typically have to `import projectname.xlwt` or use a relative import like `from . import xlwt`. Also see `sys.path`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this is an old question, I bumped into the same problem.

You normally can not install packages for Python easily. There is however a nice solution. Virtualenv creates a local instance of Python, and after installing virtualenv, you can install packages locally in your account.

Answer (score 15):

I don't think it is possible without SSH. For what it's worth, I have GoDaddy deluxe shared hosting on Linux and I was able to install
Python as follows:

Set up a new directory in /home/"your username":

```
mkdir ~/python27
cd ~/python27
```

Download and unpack Python files:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.12/Python-2.7.12.tgz
tar -xzvf Python-2.7.12.tgz
find ~/python27 -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
cd Python-2.7.12
```

Configure and install Python:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/python27
make
make install
```

Update your default Python path by modifying your bash_profile file:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Add these lines to bash_profile:

```
# Python 2.7
export PATH="$HOME/python27/bin:$PATH"
```

Confirm that the changes took place:

```
python -V #old version
source ~/.bashrc
python -V #new version
```

Install easy_setup:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py
python ez_setup.py
```

Quit SSH, log in again, and install pip:

```
easy_install pip
```

You can now add libraries as required. You can access the new version in your python applications with:

```
#! /home/"your username"/python27/Python-2.7.12/python
```

The following links were all helpful, but I needed to combine various steps for it to work for me:

http://geeksta.net/geeklog/python-shared-hosting/

https://www.godaddy.com/garage/tech/config/how-to-install-and-configure-python-on-a-hosted-server/

https://gist.github.com/BigglesZX/1610950

Comment: I needed to run source ~/.bash_profile instead of source ~/.bashrc, otherwise this worked great. Thanks!

Comment: where do you do the wget for pip? Is it in the python folder?